# Nodes Near coords hide when 0

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

Is it possible to hide nodes near coords in pgfplots when value = 0 ?

I have something like this.

[image]

And axis setting

```
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  bar width=3pt,
  nodes near coords
]
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to provide the community with some sample data as well as a (complete) [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) - something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile. It just makes it easier to work with the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As standard `node near coordinates` is `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}`.  You want to run that only if `\pgfplotspointmeta` is non-zero.  This may be tested for with `\pgfmathfloatifflags` as follows:

```
near coords={\pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}}}
```

with `0` indicating test whether the number is equal to zero, `{}` being the action if it is and the final group containing the action if it is not zero.

You don't provide the code for your plot, so here is a similar case instead:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar width=3pt,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}}}
    ]
    \addplot coordinates
    {(0,3) (1,0) (2,0) (3,1) (4,2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```